Xcode下でmacOSのCloudKitアプリを実行すると同期されるが、ArchiveしてExportすると同期されない
macOS Sonoma 14.5
Xcode15.4
質問
SwiftDataとCloudKitを使って、異なるBundle Identifierを持つアプリ同士でデータの同期を行おうとしています。Xcode下でアプリを実行するとデータが同期されるのですが、それをProduct→Archive→Distribute App→Direct Distribution→Export Notarized Appしてから.appを実行すると、一切データが同期されません。ターミナルで.appを実行しても目立ったエラーは表示されません。何か解決策をお持ちの方はいらっしゃいませんか。
